# Gauss' flux theorem for dynamic electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law

How can I prove that Gauss' flux theorem is valid for an electric field with dynamic component, I mean E = E(static) + E(dynamic)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! You're supposed to show some effort to work through the problem. See our meta site for more guidance: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It's not ! you have a delay due to the propagation of the electromagnetic's waves.

Don't forget there is two times dependent equation among the maxwell's equation !